# I can't access method from the gateway

Tags: java, spring-security

So I can access method from the original port that I chose in properties file, but I am doing auth-service so I when im trying to register a new user, I need to do it through gateway, but it doesn't work.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthConfig {


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/register", "/auth/token", "/auth/validate").permitAll()
                .and()
                .build();
    }

    
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {


    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String addNewUser(@RequestBody UserCredential userCredential){
        return authService.saveUser(userCredential);
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class AuthService {

    @Autowired
    private UserCredentialRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    public String saveUser(UserCredential credential){
        credential.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(credential.getPassword()));
        repository.save(credential);
        return "user added to the system";
    }

}
```

```
server.port=8083
spring.application.name=auth-service
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id=auth-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri=http://localhost:8083
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[0]=Path=/auth/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[0]=RewritePath=/auth/(?<segment>.*), /${segment}
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[1]=AddRequestHeader=X-Request-ServiceName, auth-service
```

o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /auth/register
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /auth/register
Hibernate: insert into user_credential (email, name, password) values (?, ?, ?)
: Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /register
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8083/register?continue to session
o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8083/error?continue to session
Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access

As you can see gateway is can not create a new user because spring security is not giving access, but I did access to every user without any roles